# JQuery .nextAll (trying to fetch value of next input in DOM) returns with "undefined"

Tags: html, jquery, dom

I try to fetch the value of an input after changing a select-field using jQuery.

```
<div class="box">
<select class="howmuch">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="box">
<p>Some Text</p>
</div>

<div class="box">
<input class="entertext" type="text" placeholder="type something" />
</div>
```

if user changes the select-input (class=howmuch) i would like to fetch the value of the next text-input (class=entertext).

```
<script>
 $(".howmuch").change(function() {
   var fetchtext = $(this).nextAll(".entertext:first").val();
   // also tried .nextall("input:first")
 });
 </script>
```

always returns "undefined"
Anybody who can help?

Comment: select has no siblings. nextAll looks at siblings

Comment: @Christoph If my answer solved your question, please consider mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to travel de dom is using [parent()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_parent.asp), [nextAll()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_nextall.asp) and [find()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_find.asp) to find the input value you need.

```js
 $(".howmuch").change(function() {
   var fetchtext = $(this).parent().nextAll().find(".entertext:first").val();
   console.log(fetchtext);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
<select class="howmuch">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="box">
<p>Some Text</p>
</div>

<div class="box">
<input class="entertext" type="text" placeholder="type something" />
</div>
```

Comment: FYI your links and link names are mixed